# regarding conversion of php app to salesforce app

Tags: salesforce1-app

I have a project for student management system running in php in my organization but now there is demand of converting that in salesforce how can i do that ?
Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. As is, there isn't enough information to give a specific answer, so this question is likely to be closed as being too broad. If you're new to Salesforce, [trailhead.salesforce.com](https://trailhead.salesforce.com) is a good place to start. Try to accomplish this by yourself first. If you find yourself running into a _specific_ problem, that's what this community shines at

Answer (score 1):

Salesforce owns the Heroku platform that can [run PHP apps](https://www.heroku.com/php) directly.

If you mean converting your PHP app into a native Salesforce app, then that is a re-write using Salesforce's [Lightning Platform](https://www.salesforce.com/products/platform/app-dev/lightning-platform/) technologies. A first step would be to learn about that platform and [Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/home) is a great way to do that starting with e.g. the [Developer Beginner](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/trails/force_com_dev_beginner) trail (that takes about 18 hours to go through). With that grounding, and given that you already have a design (presumably including a database schema) the re-write may not take too long.

Note that while the development work can be done without purchasing any licenses, to go into production usually requires licenses to be bought from Salesforce. These are priced per user per month and are not cheap.